# Automatically apply new formatting and remove time from a dynamically added Date-Time in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am new to Google sheets and don't know how to write excel/google sheet formula to apply automatic formatting to a date+time value added through an external script.

I have a CRM integrated with google sheets, and it dynamically adds current date+time to a google sheet column.

The date format it adds is `2018-04-09T17:49:59` but I want this format to be changed to `2018-04-09` and time(T17:49:59) removed. So the final product is only date `2018-04-09`

Here is the image that shows what I meant.

[image]

**Column C** represents what is being added by the CRM and **Column D** is what I want it to be.

Can anyone please help me to write the proper formula that will format the date and remove the time?

Comment: You don't need to change the formula.  Format the cells to display the format you want, which is yyyy-mm-dd.  More details can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats).

Comment: Sorry but its not clear to me. You said "you don't need to change the formula". But I don't have any formula. And the link you sent.. it does not tell how do I remove/delete "T17:49:59" from above example

Comment: In your question's title, you wrote "formula to format date".  You don't need a formula. Here is how to [change the **format** of the cells](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Questions about Google Sheets should be asked on the WebApps site rather than Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve the problem. I used `=REGEXEXTRACT(C5,"(.*)T.*")` to remove the Time from that string. And going to use the date format as is for now.

The second answer on the following stackoverflow question helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164557/remove-characters-from-a-string-after-a-certain-word-excel

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the data you want to format.
2. You can adjust the specific formatting for these values by clicking on the arrows in the value and choosing an option.
3. To delete a value from your formatting, click the value and select **Delete**.
4. Click **Apply**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I am looking for. I have updated my question, I hope that makes more sense.